# Pagination does not work, I consider fixing or new coding

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I coded a wordpress-site and since some time the pagination worked fine. Then it stopped working.

I tried different plugins, but no one works. I want to put the pagination in a special place within a self-coded loop. Therefore the plugin of bestwebsoft seemed to be the best, since it offers the option of displaying the pagination by the use of a bit of PHP. But also that does not work. The support of bestwebsoft is not helpful, they only repeat what I can read in the documentation.

My questions: 
1) Is there eventually a problem in my loop, that stops the pagination from displaying? 
2) Is it a problem that I use "Masonry" for showing the excerpts and order the excerpts in a horicontal manner? Maybe that interferes with the pagination?

```
    <div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", 
    "columnWidth": 285, "gutter": 20 }'>

    <?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post',
    'os_buch_review',
    'os_review',
    'os_classic_review',
    'os_versus',
    ),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'nopaging' => false,
    'posts_per_page' => '20',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'cat' => '-5738,-1705, -5933',
    );

    $tk_startteaser_querie = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $tk_startteaser_querie->have_posts() ) :
    ?>

    <?php
    while( $tk_startteaser_querie->have_posts() ) :
    $tk_startteaser_querie->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="grid-item">
     <a class="linkclass" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
     <h3 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

     <?php
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      the_post_thumbnail('medium');
      }
     ?>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    </div><!-- grid-item -->

   <?php
   endwhile;

    if ( function_exists( 'pgntn_display_pagination' ) ) { 
    pgntn_display_pagination( 'posts' ); 
    }

   wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>

    <?php
    else :
    esc_html_e( 'Derzeit keine Beiträge!', 'text-domain' );
    endif;
    ?>

    </div><!--grid-->
```

I want to have some kind of pagination. I would prefer a self-coded one, but could not do it. Therefore I also would accept a plugin-solution. but nothing works! Most of all i would like to know where the problem is located.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the code in `pgntn_display_pagination` function but I have modified your code with below one which will work for you.

Kindly check below code.

```
<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", 
    "columnWidth": 285, "gutter": 20 }'>

    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;  // get the current page variable and set it          
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post',
    'os_buch_review',
    'os_review',
    'os_classic_review',
    'os_versus',
    ),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'nopaging' => false,
    'posts_per_page' => '20',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'cat' => '-5738,-1705, -5933',
    'paged' => $paged // use $paged variable here
    );

    $tk_startteaser_querie = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $tk_startteaser_querie->have_posts() ) :
    ?>

    <?php
    while( $tk_startteaser_querie->have_posts() ) :
    $tk_startteaser_querie->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="grid-item">
     <a class="linkclass" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
     <h3 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

     <?php
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      the_post_thumbnail('medium');
      }
     ?>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    </div><!-- grid-item -->

   <?php
   endwhile;


 // Below is full code of pagination  

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
    'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
    'show_all'     => false,
    'type'         => 'plain',
    'end_size'     => 2,
    'mid_size'     => 1,
    'prev_next'    => true,
    'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Next', 'text-domain' ) ),
    'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Previous', 'text-domain' ) ),
    'add_args'     => false,
    'add_fragment' => '',
) );

   wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>

    <?php
    else :
    esc_html_e( 'Derzeit keine Beiträge!', 'text-domain' );
    endif;
    ?>

    </div><!--grid-->
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately there is nothing shown on the page: thrillandkill.com It should be at least "soewhere" in the page, or dont you think? Maybe it is in the source-code but not visible yet. So what I would look for in the source-code? 
Thank you
Raphael

Comment: enabled the error it may be the fatal error that is the reason its showing blank page.

Comment: No, there is no error. What I mean is: after pasting the code there is no difference. the site is just as it was before. There is no pagination visible. No change at all. 

im my code ist says: $args = array(
   ...
    'nopaging' => false,
   ...

Is that a problem?